# Rendering and invalidation cache using rowHeight in JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I came across a text :-

> As long as the current rowHeight property setting isn’t positive, the
>   TreeUI must ask the renderer for its height. Therefore, decreasing the
>   value by 1 has a side effect of invalidating the cached renderer size
>   information, causing the tree to be displayed with the proper initial
>   sizes for all the renderers.

```
renderer.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 32));

int rowHeight = tree.getRowHeight();

if (rowHeight <= 0)

 {

tree.setRowHeight(rowHeight - 1);

}
```

Could  someone explain

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? (the code snippet doesn't make much sense to me ... decrementing the rowHeight when it is zero or negative?)

Comment: I was going through a book and found the above lines hard to comprehend,especially "invalidating the cached renderer size information".